# Multiply even-indexed elements of array by 2 and odd-indexed elements of array by 3

Tags: python

I want to write a function in Python, called multiplica_2_or_3, which receives a list (lst), of
numbers,
integer or real. The function returns the tuple of numbers obtained by multiplying each element of (lst)
by 2, if it is in an even position on the list, and by 3 if it is in an odd position
list (note that the position of the 1st element is zero).

can you please help me? thanks

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Tip: Look up / research looping through a list, and the modulo operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i improved the code:

```
def multiplica_2_ou_3(lst):
lista = []
for i, e in enumerate(lst):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        lista.append(e * 3)
    else:
        lista.append(e * 2)
return tuple(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your function.
Output: (10, 14, 22)

```
def is_odd(num):
    if num == 0 or num == 1 or num == 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def multiplica_2_or_3(l):
    lista = []
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        if is_odd(i):
            lista.append(e * 3)
        else:
            lista.append(e * 2)
    return tuple(lista)

print(multiplica_2_or_3([5, 7, 11]))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! :)